# invert a ''polynomial'' with poles (sounds ridiculous, but please refer to the details)

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I recently encountered some polynomial inversion in some physics literature, the simplified version would be the following:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_nx^n=\frac{g(x)}{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}$$
where $g(x)$ is some power series in $x$. People may naturally think that $x_1$ and $x_2$ should just be two zeros of $g(x)$, but this is not true based on the literature I was referring to. Then the author says the formula can be inverted to give 
$$f_n=\frac{A}{x_1^n}+\frac{B}{x_2^n}$$
where $A$ and $B$ are the residues at $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively.

My understanding is that the summation can blow up at some values of $x$, or rather when it's outside of the region of convergence. But this is still pretty much confusing.

I apologise that I am not able to put this in a mathematically rigorous way because I myself find it extremely weird. Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: A very simple example that I have in mind is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
which is only true for $|x|<1$. If we only look at the RHS, we can definitely say that $x=1$ is a simple pole, whereas it's obviously not a pole for the LHS. This is exactly the part that confuses me and it becomes even more perplexing if we have more then one poles.

Comment: do you have ANY concrete example

Comment: please refer to the edited version

Comment: "it's obviously not a pole for the LHS" Actually, it is - if you denote that LHS by $f(x)$, then $\lim f(x)=\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 1^-$.

Comment: well, you can say that it is a singularity, but you cannot say it's a pole because a pole is defined to be an isolated singularity, whereas any $x\geq 1$ can make the series diverge and thus $x=1$ is not an isolated singularity